How can I improve this model to better fit the data?
I have some data as a function of several variables,
$$k_{ap}=f(k_{ij},\ \alpha,\ D/L).$$
The data is as shown in the three plots below.
Fig 1

Plots a-c show the ratio of $k_{ap}/k_1$ as a function of the angle $\alpha$, where $k_1$ is the maximum principal value of the symmetric 2D tensor $k_{ij}$. The three plots correspond to different values of $D/L$.
The equation I have to model this data is as follows:
$$\tag{1} k_{ap}=\sqrt{\frac{k_{ij}u_iu_j}{r_{ij}u_iu_j}}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{k_{ij}u_iu_jr_{ij}u_iu_j}(D/L)^n}{\sqrt{k_{ij}u_iu_jr_{ij}u_iu_j}+(D/L)^n}\right],$$
where,

$r_{ij}$ is the matrix inverse of $k_{ij}$, where
$$k_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}k_{xx}&k_{xy}\\
k_{yx}&k_{yy} \end{bmatrix},$$ $k_{ij}$ is symmetric, and $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the maximum and minimum principal values of $k_{ij}$, respectively.

$u_i$ is a unit vector with components $(u_x, u_y)$, and is related to $\alpha$ through a rotation matrix $R$,
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha&-\sin \alpha\\\sin \alpha&\cos \alpha \end{bmatrix},$$
such that $u_i = R_{ij}u'_j$ and $u'_j=(1, 0)$.

$n=1$ when $D/L <1$, $n=2$ when $D/L \ge 1$.


The plot below shows the values of the model (Eqn(1)) superimposed onto Fig 1. As seen, the model does OK for when the value of $D/L$ "moves away" from a value of 1, i.e., at $D/L$ values of 10 and 0.1. However, I would like to have a model that works better at $D/L$ values of 1 and near it, e.g., values of 2, 0.5, 3, 0.33, etc. I would even consider breaking this problem up such that two models are made: one for $D/L \le 1$ and $D/L \ge 1$.

So, what can be done to improve this data model, or how would you better model this data?
The data shown in Fig 1 is given below. The top row denotes values of the angle $\alpha$ in degrees. The first column denotes values of the $k_1/k_2$ ratio.
D/L = 0.1



k1/k2
0
15
30
45
60
75
90




3.3
1
0.892727033
0.644221044
0.471532133
0.381161326
0.321504354
0.303030303


10
1
0.672226146
0.34027302
0.201326729
0.133430979
0.110962067
0.1


33
1
0.403412626
0.139231392
0.068506054
0.043511464
0.03370705
0.03030303


100
1
0.213079709
0.056970078
0.025744094
0.015449403
0.01130806
0.01


333
1
0.112547202
0.023981525
0.00967445
0.005257015
0.003584386
0.003003003


1000
1
0.076737963
0.013406335
0.004828122
0.002276615
0.00127269
0.001



D/L = 1



k1/k2
0
15
30
45
60
75
90




3.3
1
0.958339761
0.774670545
0.567013539
0.420949482
0.345133948
0.303030303


10
1
0.820560164
0.617382642
0.360137357
0.195695621
0.119117442
0.1


33
1
0.820560164
0.54339162
0.259886903
0.085959045
0.041111473
0.03030303


100
1
0.820560164
0.507599835
0.207119871
0.048739942
0.016121008
0.01


333
1
0.820560164
0.507599835
0.188831142
0.033232313
0.006690553
0.003003003


1000
1
0.820560164
0.507599835
0.188831142
0.028031001
0.003740204
0.001



D/L = 10



k1/k2
0
15
30
45
60
75
90




3.3
1
0.918734836
0.809050182
0.645380666
0.459808174
0.346638902
0.303030303


10
1
0.918734836
0.71246041
0.529573665
0.309597572
0.154947313
0.1


33
1
0.918734836
0.71246041
0.466349651
0.246966494
0.08440737
0.03030303


100
1
0.918734836
0.71246041
0.466349651
0.226896722
0.061860161
0.01


333
1
0.918734836
0.71246041
0.466349651
0.226896722
0.050759984
0.003003003


1000
1
0.918734836
0.71246041
0.466349651
0.226896722
0.050759984
0.001




It would help if the data were numerical instead of images.

@Cesareo I agree. I'm looking into how to make a table with data in this stack exchange post.

@Cesareo numerical data tables have been added.
